# How to display Microsoft Office files (word and excel),pdf and video?

Tags: plugin

How can I display Microsoft Office files (word and excel),pdf and video files in a page?

Do you know any plugin?

I use RSForm where I show the submitted details once users submitted them;part of it is to upload a video and their CV, when its uploaded and displayed, it does not show the video file and word file. (refer to http://prntscr.com/6gleep for better understanding.)

You can go to http://footballteen.com/list/submission-view/25.html and as you can see below the picture there are two thing that are not show which are the word file and video file.

I have installed allvideo plugin but no luck!
I have installed ARI Docs Viewer plugin to display word and excel files but no luck as well!

I send this in RSfrom forum but no one replied!

I am using joomla 3.4.0

Would appropriate any help on this.

This is code in RSform where its for layout, I donno if it helps or not but maybe by modifiying it I would be able to display video and office files ( word and excel).

```
<div class="rsform-table" id="rsform-table3">
    <p class="rsform-main-title rsform-title">{Name:value}</p>
    <p class="rsform-big-subtitle rsform-title">{Family Name:value}</p>
    <p class="rsform-small-subtitle rsform-title">{Date of Birth:value}</p>
    <ul class="rsform-gallery">
        {if {Photo:value}}<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'clone'}"><img src="{Photo:path}" alt="" /></a></li>{/if}
        {if {Resume:value}}<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'clone'}"><img src="{Resume:path}" alt="" /></a></li>{/if}
        {if {Highlight:value}}<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'clone'}"><img src="{Highlight:path}" alt="" /></a></li>{/if}
    </ul>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Your approach simply won't work. The `<img>` tag is meant for images only (usually .jpg, .png, .gif and some others depending on browser support - [see the complete list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)).

Displaying the video shouldn't be that hard, depending on the formats allowed. If you're using AllVideos, the plugin uses the following syntax:

```
{formatORprovider}filenameORvideoID{/formatORprovider}
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
{if {Highlight:value}}<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal" rel="{handler: 'clone'}">{mp4}{Highlight:path}{/mp4}</a></li>{/if}
```

(not sure if the `{mp4}` will interfere with your code).

A better option would be to only allow YouTube videos to be inserted (also saves bandwidth). Then use this:

```
{if {Highlight:value}}<li>{youtube}{Highlight:path}{/youtube}</li>{/if}
```

Displaying word/excel/pdf files is a lot more complicated. A couple of alternatives:

- Embed the document inside an iFrame (will work on some  browsers, but requires your user to have Office installed)
- Convert to PDF and embed inside an iframe (works on most browsers)
- Upload the document to Google Docs, and get an embed code (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/143345?hl=en&rd=1)
- Display a file icon, and add a download link.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Office 365 doc in browser and clic on the... menu and choose Embed to get the code. Insert in Joomla!